# gridfs-stream createWriteStream not uploading data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, gridfs

I am using following code to create a file in mongodb. I get no error. But when i chech my `Test` database nothing is seen there uploaded. What am i doing wrong?

```
var GridStrm = require('gridfs-stream');
    console.log('Logo Upload');

    var conn = mongoose.createConnection('localhost', 'Test', 27017);

    var gfs = GridStrm(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);       

    var writeStream = gfs.createWriteStream('file.txt');
    fs.createReadStream('d:\\somepath').pipe(writestream);
```

I get the error `Error: EISDIR, read`.

I got new error :-

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: Cannot determine state of server
    at canCheckoutReader
```

I further tried the following code :-

```
req.pipe(gfs.createWriteStream({
        filename: 'test'
    }));
    res.send("Success!");
```

But still no result.

Comment: You have misinterpreted the code from the link you were given in your previous post. Yes you have created a stream but you are doing nothing with it. That post uses pipe to send it's output to the stream.

Comment: @NeilLunn see i am getting new error...:)

Comment: `EISDIR` means that you're trying to read a directory instead of a file.

Comment: Dude. Read your answer. Also note you haven't accepted the answer I gave you before even though you are using that information gained here.

Comment: Oh. Actually I didn't answer that one but just gave you a link.

Comment: @NeilLunn See what my requirement is. I want to upload an Logo image from angularJS & want to store it by GridFS. But i have no idea about GridFS. Means How it stores the image, where is stores the image.

Comment: Yes. But you are not **doing** that here.

Comment: You can post it as answer....in last post...i will accept it...

Comment: Then what am i doing wrong? pls tell me...totally confused right now.

Comment: Not needed. It was just a link. Just do as that link says. `req.pipe` things work. Don't over think this.

Comment: @NeilLunn I tried req.pipe .... It doesn't give any result

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48864/discussion-between-anup-and-neil-lunn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more minimal example

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
var fs = require('fs');

var conn = mongoose.createConnection('localhost', 'test', 27017 );

conn.once('open', function() {

    var gfs = Grid( conn.db, mongoose.mongo );

    var source = fs.createReadStream('file.txt');

    var target = gfs.createWriteStream({
        filename: 'file.txt'
    });

    source.pipe(target);

});
```

This puts into the collection:

```
> db.fs.files.find()
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("531470dc8b79087430b2e38d"),
  "filename" : "file.txt", 
  "contentType" : "binary/octet-stream",
  "length" : 138,
  "chunkSize" : 262144,
  "uploadDate" : ISODate("2014-03-03T12:09:00.896Z"),
  "aliases" : null,
  "metadata" : null,
  "md5" : "87be58f21745384bcd13743bde9ae8fb"
}
```

So your problem was:

1. When you first posted you had a stream but you were not using it.
2. You thought that was where you told it what file to use

In all the gridFS methods the filename is just a label that is sent to the server. Other methods are used to work with real files. So if you are still confused, try the code then change this line afterwards:

```
    var target = gfs.createWriteStream({
        filename: 'dont-exist.txt'
    });
```

Your same file content will be used, just with a new label on the server.

Comment: @Anup Look at the code and copy it. I put in a full working sample.

Comment: @Anup look at the code and understand why. Read up on node callbacks and if you are going to use express, read through the docs on `req` and `res` carefully.

Comment: yes i will....now my next task is to save uploaded image with `input type='file'` which the user selected...

Comment: If u r still der... i got one doubt.....in my html i have a  `input type='file'` the user selects the image from here.....and this `img` is then stored by GridFS... so is there any need to store this user selected image in a `folder`.....or it can go directly to `GridFS`